# openssl tlsv1 SSL_write sends odd additional data

Tags: openssl

I've got a problem with SSL_write(). When i call this it sends additional encrypted data before my in a separate tls-packet. It consists of 32 bytes. I patched openssl code a bit to dump this data before encryption and found out that it's real size 0x15 bytes and 0x0b bytes of padding. These 0x15 bytes seem to be senseless. But i can't understand what causes it? There is my code:

```
int sock,s;
BIO *sbio;
SSL_CTX *ctx;
SSL *ssl;
int ret;
const SSL_METHOD *meth;
SSL_CTX *ctx;

/* Global system initialization*/
SSL_library_init ();
SSL_load_error_strings ();
meth = TLSv1_server_method ();
ctx = SSL_CTX_new (meth);
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, ppcb);
ret = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "server_cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
ret = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file (ctx, "server_key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

/*sock is accepted connection*/
sbio = BIO_new_socket (sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_bio (ssl, sbio, sbio);
ret = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, "TLSv1");
ret = SSL_accept (ssl);

char buf[BUFSIZE];
/*preparing buffer*/
r = SSL_write (ssl, buf, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that it tried to flush buffer before sending my data. But it is empty, so the packet contained 0x14 bytes of hash of empty buffer and 0x0c bytes of padding (sorry for wrong numbers in the description above - there was a mistake in output). While searching i came accross some option list in ssl.h and tried to set: 
`SSL_set_options(ssl, SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS);`
So, it solved my problem,  but i still don't know the reason of sending empty fragments before my data.